# Android: Show a non predetermined number of fragments in a tab View

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, tabs

I am getting from JSON some data that I would like to display in a tab view.
From the JSON (let's talk about venues), I can retrieve anywhere between 1 and 25 venues. They all follow the same architecture, and the JSON is converted to an `Venues = ArrayList<Venue>.` 
What I would like to do is that for each Venue in Venues, add a tab that follow only one type of xml and one type of Java, but still are independant.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: add values to listview and Create Custom Listview Adapter for Custom Listview raw..

Comment: that's what I thought about doing.... Still struggling.. do you have any sample code? Thanks